# Finding an orthogonal matrix for a 3x2

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I know how to find an orthogonal matrix for a $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ matrix. However I have been stuck on how to do this for a $3\times2$ matrix.
The question is how to find a non-zero $3\times2$ matrix B which is orthogonal to      $A= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\3&4\\5&6\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: So you want to find one for $2\times2$ or $3\times3?$

Comment: No, I know how to do those but I have no idea how to do the same for a 3x2 as I cannot find determinant?

Comment: With respect to which inner product (\bilinear form) is the matrix supposed to be orthogonal to $A$?  Frobenius?